# Which USB WiFi adapters work with Ubuntu out of the box (without installing anything at all)?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I've only found this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported and it's very old, many of the sub-pages are last edited in 2015 or 2016, and many vendors are simply not there at all.

I need to order a Wi-Fi dongle for a relative who almost doesn't know how to use a PC and (until this new dongle starts functioning) has no Internet access. Their PC has Ubuntu and nothing else. So I need to know in advance if a given Wi-Fi dongle will automatically work with Ubuntu. Do you know where to look for this info?

Comment: In the netherlands we have sellers that actually list Linux https://www.bol.com/nl/l/wifi-adapters/N/16400+4277702487/ All those will work so pick one of those in your country. As for help from askubuntu: we do not support hardware: If an adaptor does not work you/someone need/s to file a bug report against the driver :) In general: USB devices  work on Linux. That driver is generic. It is just the software you get that comes with it that will not work.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind! I think your comment is good enough to be an accepted answer.